# how to get list of bluetooth devices using ExternalAccessory.framework

Tags: ios, bluetooth

how to get list of bluetooth devices using ExternalAccessory.framework not using Gamekid framework, core bluetooth framework. please write me examp0le of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The External Accessory framework is only get list apple devices...By Apple

> The External Accessory framework is designed to allow iOS applications
>   to communicate only with hardware accessories that are developed under
>   Apple's MFi licensee program. MFi compliant accessories can be
>   implemented as wired devices, meaning they plug in to the iOS device's
>   30-pin connector, or as wireless devices, whereby they use Bluetooth
>   as the communication channel. Either way, an application that uses the
>   External Accessory framework will not be notified of an accessory's
>   presence unless the accessory identifies itself as being MFi
>   compliant, i.e., it was specifically designed to interface with an iOS
>   application.

if you want  get the list only **apple device** use sample code

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] 
                        connectedAccessories]; 
for (EAAccessory *obj in accessories)
{ 
    NSLog(@"Found accessory named: %@", obj.name);
}
```

you must include the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key in your app’s Info.plist file.

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
```

This key contains an array of strings that identify the communications protocols that your app supports.

Comment: thank you, yes I want only apple device. I use this code, but list of devices is empty, although the iphone (settings -> General -> Bluetooth-> Devices) displays Device which can be pear.

Comment: are you sure you  import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h>in your class and must include the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key in your app’s Info.plist file

Comment: i import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h> and include the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols.

Comment: please check EAAccessory addrees

Comment: EAAccessory addrees: 0x13df90

Comment: Your Buletooth name or number

Comment: please clean you derived data folder and clean your project and add the key UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols.  in info.plist

Comment: i opean my-info.plist with notepad and add this line <key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>, is it good?

Comment: No, Right Click On Info.plist File and click on Open With then chose Souce Code

Comment: thank you, this proplems resolved, it's really was in Info.plist. It should look like <key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
 <array>
  <string>com.apple.p1</string>
where com.apple.p1 -  the communications protocols that your app supports
  <string>com.apple.p2</string>
 </array>

Comment: how could i get the list of non apple bluetoth devices?

Comment: it can be only mfi - devices

Comment: What is com.apple.p1 and com.apple.p2? I put these in as values?