# Communicating with Bluetooth MFi device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory, mfi, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an application that communicates with automotive head unit. This head unit supports MFi.

I started with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202161/how-to-get-list-of-bluetooth-devices-using-externalaccessory-framework) question and I was successful in connecting my iPhone via USB. It appeared in list of connected devices.

But when I'm pairing it via bluetooth there is no devices.

Comment: What's the error? A little bit of your code?